# get verified user to mysql database

Tags: java, php, android, sinch

I previously used [a service](http://www.cognalys.com), where I could receive user data from an xml file on the verification service server, if the user verified his phonenumber. as this service is not working that stable, i'm trying to get into [sinch](http://www.sinch.com) (as im not that pro). 
so in general:

is there  an xml file on sinch, where my verified users are stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no XML file in sinch, you get a callback every time a verification occurs.

https://www.sinch.com/docs/verification/rest/#verificationcallbackapi

Answer (score 0):

For json file

```
$data = file_get_contents('filename');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

For xml file

```
$data = simplexml_load_file('filename');
```

Use this to view the data

```
print_r($data)
```

Comment: this is totally correct, but I didn't made my question clear enough, sorry about that. I meant, if there is an xml file on sinch, where my veified users are stored.